# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: angular

I am migrating from Angular 5 to Angular 8 application and came across the below error. Not sure what the problem is ?

Error

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.  'unknown' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

Code

```
public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<T>(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<T> {
        const url = this._baseUrl + this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId;
        return this.http.get<T>(url, this.getRequestHeaders())
        .pipe(catchError(error => {
            return this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId));
        }));
    }
```

After further dwelling in the code , I can see there are there are several service and endpoints classes defined.I am still not convinced why generics is used as  each endpoint class has its own getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint method

**Service class**

```
@Injectable()
export class AddAccountService {

    constructor(private _addAccountEndpoint: AddAccountEndpoint){}

    getClientCompanyAccounts(clientCompanyId: number){
        return this._addAccountEndpoint.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<AccountModel[]>(clientCompanyId);
    }
}
```

**Endpoint class**

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AddAccountEndpoint extends EndpointFactory {
        private readonly _baseUrl: string = this.configurations.baseUrl;
        private readonly _clientCompanyAccountsUrl = '/api/client-company-accounts/';

        constructor(http: HttpClient, protected configurations: ConfigurationService, injector: Injector) {
            super(http, configurations, injector);
        }

        public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<T>(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<T> {
            const url = this._baseUrl + this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId;
            return this.http.get<T>(url, this.getRequestHeaders())
            .pipe(catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId));
            }));
        }
    }
```

**Service class**

```
        @Injectable()
    export class ClientService {

        constructor(private router: Router, private clientEndpoint: ClientEndpoint) {

        }

            getClientCompanyAccounts(clientCompanyId: number) {
               return this.clientEndpoint.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<SettlementAccountModel[]>(clientCompanyId);
            }
        }
```

**Endpoint class**

```
        @Injectable()
    export class ClientEndpoint extends EndpointFactory {
        private readonly _baseUrl: string = this.configurations.baseUrl;
            public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<T>(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<T> {
            return this.http.get<T>(this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId, this.getRequestHeaders())
                .pipe(catchError(error => {
                    return this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId));
                }));
        }
        }
```

Do I need to write the endpoints and service classes like this respectively

```
 getClientCompanyAccounts(clientCompanyId: number) {
        return this.clientEndpoint.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId);
    }

    public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<AccountModel[]> {
        const url = this._baseUrl + this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId;
        return this.http.get<AccountModel[]>(url, this.getRequestHeaders())
        .pipe(catchError(error => {
            return this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId));
        }));
    }

 getClientCompanyAccounts(clientCompanyId: number){
        return this._addAccountEndpoint.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId);
    }

public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<SettlementAccountModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<SettlementAccountModel[]>(this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId, this.getRequestHeaders())
            .pipe(catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId));
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Why is the method generic? How could the server return something which depends on which type you chose to call the method with? Especially given you call it without specifying any generic type. The nackend returns something like a `ClientCompanyAccounts`, right? So remove the generic type T, and use `this.http.get<ClientCompanyAccounts>`. And change the return type to `Observable<ClientCompanyAccounts>`.

Comment: I am trying to understand that myself. Its old code and I am trying to upgrade. All I did is used pipeable operator and used catchError operator. It was initially only catch

Comment: catchError must return an observable, so the error, I reckon is due to type mutation of handleError method - it must return the same type

Comment: I have just updated the post to show how endpoint and service classes are used in the application. Is it justifable

Comment: replace **`T`** with **any**

Comment: Is that better to what I have mentioned in the post above. Just updated a while ago

Comment: @Timothy : So if thats the case how should the handle error look like ?

Comment: @Tom use tap operator instead of catchError. Its not gonna change initial observable and will allow you to catch errors in component themselves, in your current approach there will be no way to catchError in components (or you have to throw an error ahead with throwError)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to catch error as following.

```
public getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint<T>(clientCompanyId: number): Observable<T> {
    const url = this._baseUrl + this._clientCompanyAccountsUrl + clientCompanyId;

    return this.http.get<T>(url, this.getRequestHeaders())
    .pipe(tap(_ => {}, err => this.handleError(error, () => this.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint(clientCompanyId))));
}
```

Because if you use catchError it returns an error response as observable itself... So lets say you have following schenario - you want to log errors somewhere, or show toastr or whatever and later on in a component which consumes this service you want to handle errors as well, if you catchError prior, you will not be able to handle error responses in components. Ie

```
myService.getClientCompanyAccountsEndpoint().subscribe(res => (), err => (
// Will never be reached because error will be in res callback
))
```

Tap operator is defined as

```
tap({
  next: val => {
    // on next 11, etc.
    console.log('on next', val);
  },
  error: error => {
    console.log('on error', error.message);
  },
  complete: () => console.log('on complete')
})
```

Comment: can you also explain this tap(_ => {},

Comment: Tap operator has 3 callbacks: next, error, complete. In order to reach error callback you need to define the first one..